# xcode error with armv7 architecture and react native project

Tags: xcode, react-native

I'm getting the following error in XCode (12.4) when trying to build a RN-project in release mode on a real device:

> the linked library libpods is missing one or more architectures required by this target armv7

I have "solved" this issue bij adding "armv7" as an excluded architecture in the build settings of my project. The the project now works as expected, but I'm not sure **why** this error is occuring. I don't want to run into any problems after I've added my app to the app store.

My device is a iPhone 6S with iOS 14.4.